# How to create the illusion of particles been left behind in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making an endless runner game were the camera is static and the environment is moving from top to bottom, the player is a rocket facing upwards that can only move left or right. When the player collides with an obstacle it spawns particles to show an explosion. What i want is to show the illusion of the particles been left behind as the camera is moving up. But since my camera is static i have to move them backwards myself to give an illusion of the camera going up how do i go about doing that?

Here is my code:

```
public Particle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    rotDirection = MathUtils.random.nextBoolean() ? -1 : 1;
    dx = MathUtils.cos(MathUtils.random(MathUtils.PI2));
    dy = MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.random(MathUtils.PI2));
    xSpeed = MathUtils.random(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);
    ySpeed = MathUtils.random(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);
    rotation = MathUtils.random(360);
    rotationSpeed = MathUtils.random(MIN_ROT_SPEED, MAX_ROT_SPEED);
}

public void update(float delta){
    x += dx * xSpeed * delta;
    y += dy * ySpeed * delta;
    rotation += rotDirection * rotationSpeed * delta;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using randoms to set dy and ySpeed.
Then you change the y value using these 2 random values and deltaTime.
If you want to move the particle in a specific direction you cannot use random values to move it.

Try having a float yMoveSpeed and add it to y.

```
public void update(float delta){
    x += dx * xSpeed * delta;
    y += dy * ySpeed * delta;
    rotation += rotDirection * rotationSpeed * delta;
    y += yMoveSpeed * delta;
}
```

That should at least make it move in a direction.

Another solution could be to use the particle system and editor bundled with libgdx. (in gdx-tools)
[Game From Scratch tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/11/03/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-15-Particles-Part-One-2D-Particles.aspx)